# How to enter multiple numpy arrays to a function and return multiple outputs

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, function

For example, the following works fine:

```
import numpy as np
time = np.linspace(0, 3, 4)
func = lambda x : x
print(func(time))

>>> [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

I want to do the equivalent for functions that take vectors as an input. For example, I want the following to happen:

```
inps = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
sum_func = lambda x : x[0] + x[1]
print(sum_func(inps))

>>> [3, 7, 11]
```

But what ends up being returned is `[3, 3]`, which is just the sum of the first two elements in each column. How can I make what I want to happen actually happen?

If possible, I would like to avoid for loops. For example, the following works

```
inps = np.array([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]])
def func(x):
    vals = []
    for x in x.tolist():
        vals.append(x[0] + x[1])
    return np.array(vals)
print(func(inps))

>>> [3, 7, 11]
```

but is there another way to do it?

Comment: `inps[0]` is the first "row", `np.array([1,2])`.  try that without the function layer.  `inps[:,0]` is the first column, `np.array([1,3,5])`.  `numpy` arrays are more than nested lists.  `array` indexing is powerful (and a bit overwhelming to a beginner).  And as others show, functions `np.sum` take an `axis` (or `axes`) parameter that gives even more power.

Comment: @hpaulj this is what I was looking for, thanks. I was already aware of the sum function, I just used my ```sum_func``` to give a basic example.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy includes tons of functions to manipulate numpy arrays. You should be aware of [the documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/index.html). [Here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.math.html) is the list of just the mathematical functions.

The [sum function](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) will come in handy here since we want to sum each row:

```
import numpy as np

inps = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
sum_func = lambda x : np.sum(x, axis=1)
print(sum_func(inps))

>>> [ 3  7 11]
```

This will sum along the 1st axis which corresponds to the rows (remember in Python we start counting at 0).